# Is it possible to reset my version numbering when using clickOnce

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

I have a WinForms app which is deployed via clickOnce. It's set up to check for a newer version on startup. Historically this app has had releases numbered using the current date, ie 2014.11.11 would be a version release today.

I would like to go to using a system where the version number means something, however I don't want to start with 2015.1.1. Is it possible to bring my major version number down to a single digit, and still have updates picked up when run by the users?

The app is .Net 4.0, being built worked on Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not reset your version numbers. See following [help from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haeyaeba.aspx).

> The ClickOnce Publish Version property determines whether or not the application that you are publishing will be treated as an update. 
>   Each time version is incremented, the application will be published as an update.
>   ...
>   You should never decrement a version number; doing so could cause unpredictable update behavior.

You can however choose a version number as single number like 2015001 as long as this number is bigger than your last version, like 2015001  > 2014.11.11.

If you want to go to a single digit, you need to publish an application from fresh, like it is a completely new application.

Instead of using your version numbers as day numbers, I suggest that you use following approach.

```
Year.MajorVersion.MinorVersion 
2015.001.001
Office 2015 , Service Pack 1, Patch 1
```